# How does adding extra row and column of ones affect a matrix's inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, block-matrices

I'm working on a homework problem, and I'm stuck.  I guess my linear algebra still needs some work...

I've arrived at

$\mathbf{D}=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\mathbf{C} & \mathbf{1}^T \\
\mathbf{1} & 0
\end{matrix}
\right]
$

where $\mathbf{C}$ is a $n$ by $n$ matrix and $\mathbf{1}$ is a $n$ by $1$ vector of all ones.  I need to find $\mathbf{D}^{-1}$.  Can I express it in terms of $\mathbf{C}^{-1}$?  Can I proceed at all?  Does it help if $\mathbf{C}$ is symmetric?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried any examples? Make up some $2\times2$ matrix $C$, and see how/whether $D^{-1}$ relates to $C^{-1}$?

Comment: I have tried that.  It's difficult to see any relation... but I guess I don't know what to look for.

Comment: Look up the "Schur complement", or see my comment on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182309/block-inverse-of-symmetric-matrices

Comment: Computing the Schur complement requires that $D$ (ie, the component in the lower right) be invertable, which it isn't...  EDIT: Or at least that's what my cursory reading of the wiki article says.  Your linked comment is much more helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: How is it that you're asking how to find $\mathbf D^{-1}$ if you believe that $\mathbf D$ isn't invertible?

Comment: Have you tried block wise inversion? I think $D$ will be invertible provided $\sum_{i,j}C_{i,j}^{-1}\neq0$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $D$ in the wiki article, ie, the the component in the lower right, ie 0.  The linked question is more than sufficient to answer my question.  Thanks for the helpful replies.

Comment: @PaulAccisano I think you'll find that you need to permute blocks (at least mentally) so that $\mathbf C$ rather than $0$ comes into the lower-right position of $D$ in the [WP article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) (with all the mention of Schur complement, I thought at least one link to it would be useful).