# Proof of a Determinant Identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have a matrix identity that I wish to prove, which relates the determinant of a matrix to determinants of sub-matrices (essentially, cofactors of the larger matrix). In general terms, consider the matrix:

$$M=\left(\matrix{a & \vec{m}^\top & b \\ \vec{g} & N & \vec{h} \\ c & \vec{k}^\top & d}\right),$$

and let us write $\Delta=\det(M)$. We can also write the determinants of various sub-matrices of $M$ as cofactors, such as

$$a_c = \left|\matrix{N & \vec{h} \\ \vec{k}^\top & d}\right|,$$

for example. Under this formulation, the identity that I wish to prove is

$$\det(N) = \frac{a_cd_c - b_cc_c}{\Delta}.$$

I understand that this can be done by making use of a slight modification of the method employed in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/208021/43193) to another matrix question, where the procedure is performed not on the inverse but rather on the adjoint (the inverse multiplied by the determinant).

However, after a fruitless attempt to carry this out myself I feel that it would be a better use of my time to allow someone with a deeper understanding of the matter to fill in the appropriate steps that I'm clearly missing.

Comment: You have seen [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices), I presume?

Comment: Thanks, I have. Unfortunately something so simple hasn't worked for me so far. I'd be interested if you knew of a straightforward use of block matrix determinants prove the result in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the formula you want is the [Desnanot-Jacobi identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodgson_condensation#The_Desnanot-Jacobi_identity).

Comment: Wow, so it is! I thought I'd looked everywhere and couldn't locate what I had as a named identity. This will certainly open up a whole new avenue of investigation!

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula given previously where this
$$\pmatrix{\mathbf A & \mathbf b\\ \mathbf c^T & d}^{-1} =  \pmatrix{\mathbf E & \mathbf f\\ \mathbf g^T & h}$$
gives this
$$\mathbf{A}^{-1} = E - \frac{\mathbf{f}\mathbf{g}^T}{h}$$

As hinted, using your matrix
$$M=\left(\matrix{a & \vec{m}^\top & b \\ \vec{g} & N & \vec{h} \\ c & \vec{k}^\top & d}\right)$$
look at the inverse times the determinant, so that we have the matrix of cofactors
$$ \Delta M^{-1} = \left(\matrix{a_c & \vec{m}_c^\top & b_c \\ \vec{g}_c & N_c & \vec{h}_c \\ c_c & \vec{k}_c^\top & d_c}\right)$$
and thus that
$$ M^{-1} = \frac{1}{\Delta}\left(\matrix{a_c & \vec{m}_c^\top & b_c \\ \vec{g}_c & N_c & \vec{h}_c \\ c_c & \vec{k}_c^\top & d_c}\right)$$
Use the formula to find the matrix of cofactors of the sub-matrix. Remember that the matrix of cofactors is obtained from the inverse times the determinant, so we are looking for an expression for
$$d_c\left(\matrix{a & \vec{m}^\top \\ \vec{g} & N}\right)^{-1}$$
The top left element of this will give you the determinant for $N$.

Here we go:
$$\left(\matrix{a & \vec{m}^\top \\ \vec{g} & N}\right)^{-1} =\frac{1}{\Delta}\left(\matrix{a_c - \frac{b_cc_c}{d_c}& \star \\ \star & \star \\ }\right)= \frac{1}{\Delta d_c}\left(\matrix{d_c a_c - b_cc_c& \star \\ \star & \star \\ }\right)$$
$$\Rightarrow d_c\left(\matrix{a & \vec{m}^\top \\ \vec{g} & N}\right)^{-1} =\frac{1}{\Delta}\left(\matrix{d_c a_c - b_cc_c& \star \\ \star & \star \\ }\right) $$

And you have your formula
$$\operatorname{det}(N)=\frac{d_c a_c - b_cc_c}{\Delta}$$

Comment: Thank you for all your assistance Adam, that has certainly made clear for me what's going on with the cofactors now.