# Quadratic form minimization

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization

Suppose that $A$ is an $n\times k$ matrix with $n>k$. What vector $x\in \mathbb{R}^k$ minimizes the following quadratic form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&x^{\top}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
n & \boldsymbol{1}^{\top}A  \\
A^{\top}\boldsymbol{1} & A^{\top}A
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
x
\end{bmatrix}?
$$
Here $\boldsymbol{1}$ is a vector of ones. When $k=1$, it is easy to show that $x^*=A^{\top}1/n$ by explicitly inverting the matrix in the middle.

Comment: What is the problem with your method when k does not equal 1? I worked out a solution and it is the same as what you have for any k.

Comment: @AsAnExerciseProve Thanks. I'll try to make those computations.

Comment: This is exactly what I did and there is a nice cancellation that gives you the answer Robert posted.

Comment: It might be helpful to note that
$$
\pmatrix{n & \boldsymbol{1}^{\top}A  \\
A^{\top}\boldsymbol{1} & A^{\top}A} = 
\pmatrix{1 & 0\\0 & A}^\top \pmatrix{n & \mathbf 1^\top\\ \mathbf 1 & I_n}
\pmatrix{1 & 0\\0 & A}
$$

Comment: @AsAnExerciseProve What formula did you use for the explicit inverse of the matrix in the middle?

Comment: @BenGrossmann https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182309/block-inverse-of-symmetric-matrices. It actually gives the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a\in\mathbb{R},$ $b\in\mathbb{R}^k$ and $C\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times k}$ such that
$$
\begin{bmatrix} n  & \boldsymbol{1}^{\top}A \\
A^{\top} \boldsymbol{1} & A^{\top}A
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
= \begin{bmatrix} a  & b^{\top} \\
b & C
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Note that $C$ is symmetric and positive definite, because it is a principle submatrix of an invertible matrix that in turn is the product of a matrix and its transpose:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} n  & \boldsymbol{1}^{\top}A \\
A^{\top} \boldsymbol{1} & A^{\top}A
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
\boldsymbol{1} & A
\end{bmatrix}^{\top}
\begin{bmatrix} 
\boldsymbol{1} & A
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then $$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ x\end{bmatrix}^{\top}
\begin{bmatrix} n  & \boldsymbol{1}^{\top}A \\
A^{\top} \boldsymbol{1} & A^{\top}A
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ x\end{bmatrix}
= x^{\top}C x + x^{\top}b + b^{\top}x + a \\
\phantom{x} \\
= (Cx+b)^{\top}C^{-1}(Cx+b)-b^{\top}C^{-1}b+a
$$
Therefore, without knowing $a$, $b$ and $C$, we know that we get the minimum if $Cx+b=0,$ this means, when $x=-C^{-1}b.$

We do not need the formula for the inverse of a block matrix to proceed. From the definition of $a,$ $b$ and $C$, we get
$$
\begin{bmatrix} n  & \boldsymbol{1}^{\top}A \\
A^{\top} \boldsymbol{1} & A^{\top}A
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} a  & b^{\top} \\
b & C
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} *  & n b^{\top}+ \boldsymbol{1}^{\top}A C\\
* & *
\end{bmatrix} = I
$$
which means $\;n b^{\top}+ \boldsymbol{1}^{\top}A C = 0\;$ or $\;bn + CA^{\top}\boldsymbol{1} = 0\;$ or $\;\frac{1}{n}A^{\top}\boldsymbol{1} = -C^{-1}b = x.$

Answer (score 1):

The inverse of the mid matrix is given by
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
n & \boldsymbol{1}^{\top}A  \\
A^{\top}\boldsymbol{1} & A^{\top}A
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
(\boldsymbol{1}^{\top}M_A\boldsymbol{1})^{-1} & -\frac{\boldsymbol{1}^{\top}A}{n}(A^{\top}M_{\boldsymbol{1}}A)^{-1} \\
-(A^{\top}M_{\boldsymbol{1}}A)^{-1}\frac{A^{\top}\boldsymbol{1}}n &(A^{\top}M_{\boldsymbol{1}}A)^{-1}
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $M_B=I-B(B^{\top}B)^{-1}B$. Differentiating the quadratic form w.r.t. $x$, one gets the first order condition:
$$
-2(A^{\top}M_{\boldsymbol{1}}A)^{-1}\frac{A^{\top}\boldsymbol{1}}{n} +2(A^{\top}M_{\boldsymbol{1}}A)^{-1} x^*=0.
$$
Thus,
$$
x^*=\frac{A^{\top}\boldsymbol{1}}{n}.
$$